# ffmpeg: concat demux delay issue

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I noticed that concat demux of ffmpeg generates a discrepancy in the timestamp, the videos chosen for the concatenation are previously encoded with closed gop, same frame-rate and same resolution.
The videos have also fixed duration without decimals.

The time stamp of the videos chosen for the concatenzaion are regular every two seconds without decimals.
But after the concatenation process I can see a discrepancy in the timestamp that occurs between one video and another:

```
[...]
382.021016
384.021016
386.021016 the concat demux effect:
388.043047
390.043047
392.043047
[...]
```

test done with the following command

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries frame=key_frame,pkt_pts_time -of csv=print_section=0 input.mp4 | awk -F',' '/^1,/{print $2}'
```

I can also note that the timestamp of the concatenation starts with decimals that in the input video there aren't.

Is there somebody who can help me to get aligned overall timestamp without re-encode all again?

Thanks!

Massimo

Comment: Concat without mapping audio and check.

Comment: Hi! @Mulvya may i ask how to? i try to add -map 0 after -i with same result, the full commmand i use is: ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i 360list.txt -map 0 -t $TOTDUR -c copy ../output/360set.mp4, THANKS!

Comment: Use `-map 0:v` for video only

Comment: I got the same behaviour

Comment: what's about -force_key_frames expr:gte(0,50*2), it is correct 0 for time, 50 for  frames multiply by 2 as seconds?

Comment: With `-c copy` there's no encoding so no keyframes to create.

Comment: Thanks for your help, may i ask a suggestion to avoid so much time needed: which kind of concat for videos with same frame rate and rosolution but with any timestamp encoding etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation I encode the videos and then concatening. To run concat without copying the encoding increases a lot the time required..
I have to understand and resolve the discrepancy that occurs between videos  PTS timestamp.